# Prevent to remove script section of package.json (library angular)

Tags: angular6

I made a library with angular 6. When I build the library, script section of `package.json` will be removed.
How can I prevent this?(I need script section after library was built)

How to build: `ng build --prod MyLibraryName`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Angular library uses `ng-packagr` package. When you generete a library by cli, `ng-package.json` will be added into your library(for setting of the package).

If you add `"keepLifecycleScripts": true` into `ng-package.json`, the script section of the `package.json` won't be removed in building the library.

Comment: `--prod` is no more supported on build command. Therefore `ng-package.prod.json` is also not available. Updating `ng-package.json` with the same parameter does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.3.0 of the ng-packagr, you need to add the keepLifecycleScripts-flag to the package.json, not to the ng-package.prod.json:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "..."
  },
  "ngPackage": {
    "keepLifecycleScripts": true
  }
}
```

Comment: As of ng-packagr v9 this no longer seems to have any effect, even though `keepLifecycleScripts` is still in their JSON schema, the scripts are still being stripped during a build with it set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

**Just to help if someone had the same problem I had:**

After I've edited the package.json as described by Morzeta, executing `ng build --prod` resulted on a different destination path for the final build. The default is `{workspace}/dist/{projectName}`, after the change this became `projects/{projectName}/dist`.

I had some hard time trying to find why this happened. Debugging ng-packagr on node_modules, I came to find that when you configure your package.json as described the dest property is resolved to `projects/{projectName}/dist`, the solution is to place the dest property on package.json again:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "..."
  },
  "ngPackage": {
    "dest": "../../dist/{your-project-name-here}",
    "keepLifecycleScripts": true
  }
}
```